# Form validation with error/success icon and a tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to validate input fields on a form. I need an error/success icon inside of a input field, and a tooltip bubble with a message on the right side, but only for the error input.

I would like it to look something like this:

```
Name: [some entry  (error/success icon)]
```

If entry is valid:

```
Name: [some entry  (success icon)]
```

If entry is invalid:

```
Name: [some entry  (error icon)] <Toolip bubble with a message "Not valid"
```

I don't have idea how to accomplish both things at the same time.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6dhs0af/

Comment: waaa! how much javascript/jquery you have in your jsfiddle i see you worked hard to find a solution\

Comment: For the icons in the input fields you should try this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms on the "With optional icons". And for the tooltip, the bootstrap's popovers are rather cool i think : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: You probably don't even need js to do this. There are :valid and :invalid pseudo selectors in css, that you can use to do this kind of stuff. edit: example here: http://codepen.io/flowbob/pen/bNYYJg

Comment: @LeZohan68 just add a plugin of cupple of kb to do one think

Comment: @schliflo how about ie8-9

Comment: I do agree, but i find the bootstrap components rather cool, and if he discovers it, he'll probably use other stuff in it

Comment: @madalinivascu just throw enough js at it and it will work... joking aside: If legacy support is needed, a purely css based solution is not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you also can try using jquery plugin, this maybe helps [Best jQuery plugin to validate form fields](http://formvalidation.io/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
```

here is an example [working](http://fiddle.jshell.net/w6gpn35v/) on fiddle